# Automatically continue an ordered list in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, html, html-lists

I want to create an ordered list, break it (i.e. write some paragraph) and then continue the same ordered list, from the number where I left. Something like this:

> List starts here:
>
> 1. Item 1
> 2. Item 2
>
> This line is not a part of the ordered list.
>
> 3. Item 3
> 4. Item 4
> 5. Item 5

I tried many methods after research. One of them that I found interesting is:

```
List starts here:

    <ol class="begin">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ol>

    This line is not a part of the ordered list.
    <ol class="continue">
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ol>
```

But this won't work for me. This is the output that I get when I post this code in wordpress:

[image]
Is there any way of continuing a previous ordered list in html?
I want to continue ordered list automatically without using start="n" tag.

Comment: @j08691: added the 'output' that I get when I run this code.

Comment: As you have mentioned that you are using `wordpress`, go to `text` and simply put what I have mentioned below. Your problem would be solved.

Comment: @NathanL thanks a lot but how do I make changes to css using wordpress? I can only write HTML code in text part. Anything else that I write resets as soon as I take the preview.

Comment: Yes. You also need to add a class to your `ol` to prevent this effect on other paragraphs. For more details, check this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/18uk6hcd/6/ - @Ayse

Comment: In current (2020) wordpress, you can click on any numbered list and look for "block settings" on the right, which should have a "start value" field that you can set to any value. If you don't see this, it could be because your block isn't being treated as a numbered list. Try creating a new block starting with `1. blah blah` and it should automatically become a numbered list.

Answer (score 4):

Use `<ol start="3">` to achieve what you are looking for.

**For instance,**

The Code:

```
<ol class="begin">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ol>

    This line is not a part of the ordered list.
    <ol class="continue" start="3">
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ol>
```

Live:
[Demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/18uk6hcd/)

Hope this helps.

**Edit**:

If you do not want to hard-code, then you can do as below.

The code:

```
<ol class="begin">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2
        <p>
        This line is not a part of the ordered list.
        </p>
        </li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ol>
```

Live:
[Demo link 2](https://jsfiddle.net/18uk6hcd/2/)

Just in case, if you want the `p` to be out of the number indent, then you need to declare a `text-indent` with corresponding indent value.

Live:
[Demo - 3](https://jsfiddle.net/18uk6hcd/6/)

Additionally, if you want that to remain inside the DOM and do not break for small screens, use the below code.

```
.indent-p {
   margin-left: -40px;
}
```

Live:
[Demo - 4](https://jsfiddle.net/18uk6hcd/5/)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Just updated my question. I want this to continue automatically, can't hard code a number.

Comment: Want the paragraph to be indented out of the list :(

Comment: Hi @NathanL good solution. maybe change `text-indent` to `position: relative;` and `left: -40px;` will more flexible :D

Comment: @twxia Thanks. No. `position:relative;` is not for this purpose. Use only when you want to work exclusively with `divs` to change their positioning. For text, use `text-indent`. Also, what difference does this make?

Comment: @NathanL because `text-indent` will break the `box model`. If you want to style all `p` in the DOM, it might be broken in this `p` (like a obvious case: `padding-right`).

Comment: @twxia - No. Only `position: absolute;` does that.

Comment: See this two jsfiddle result in small width(maybe 320px?), second one will get broken in some case, so I mean left will more flexible :D : https://jsfiddle.net/1uvsbst3/1 , https://jsfiddle.net/18uk6hcd/4

Comment: In that case, if you do `margin-left:-40px;` that will also work - @twxia - Lets leave to the OP for their requirement.

Comment: @twxia - So bottomline, I feel, `position` should be avoided, but `text-indent` or `margins`, etc should be preferred .. Thanks for putting forward your inputs.